# Android Quickblox video call loudspeaker is not automatically on

Tags: android, quickblox, quickblox-android

I have implemented quickblox for video calling in android , iOS and web. But in android I have face the one issue when we receive the video call then loudspeaker of the phone is not automatically on. I want to loudspeaker is automatically on when I receive the video call.

My sample code for audio manager :-

```
audioManager = AppRTCAudioManager.create(this);

    isVideoCall = QBRTCTypes.QBConferenceType.QB_CONFERENCE_TYPE_VIDEO.equals(currentSession.getConferenceType());
    if (isVideoCall) {

        audioManager.setDefaultAudioDevice(AppRTCAudioManager.AudioDevice.SPEAKER_PHONE);


        Log.d(TAG, "AppRTCAudioManager.AudioDevice.SPEAKER_PHONE");
    } else {
        audioManager.setDefaultAudioDevice(AppRTCAudioManager.AudioDevice.EARPIECE);
        audioManager.setManageSpeakerPhoneByProximity(SettingsUtil.isManageSpeakerPhoneByProximity(this));
        Log.d(TAG, "AppRTCAudioManager.AudioDevice.EARPIECE");
    }

    audioManager.setOnWiredHeadsetStateListener((plugged, hasMicrophone) -> {
        if (callStarted) {
            Toaster.shortToast("Headset " + (plugged ? "plugged" : "unplugged"));
        }
    });

    audioManager.setBluetoothAudioDeviceStateListener(connected -> {
        if (callStarted) {
            Toaster.shortToast("Bluetooth " + (connected ? "connected" : "disconnected"));
        }
    });
```

And when i try to control the audio stream manager by adding below lines then my app is crashed

```
   QBRTCAudioTrack localAudioTrack = currentSession.getMediaStreamManager().getLocalAudioTrack();
    localAudioTrack.setEnabled(true); // enable or disable audio stream
```

Crash report :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{.quickblox_videocalling.activities.CallActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc.QBRTCAudioTrack com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc.QBMediaStreamManager.getLocalAudioTrack()' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2957)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc.QBRTCAudioTrack com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc.QBMediaStreamManager.getLocalAudioTrack()' on a null object reference
at com.ahgp.quickblox_videocalling.activities.CallActivity.initAudioManager(CallActivity.java:396)
at com.ahgp.quickblox_videocalling.activities.CallActivity.onCreate(CallActivity.java:192)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7183)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1220)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2910)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374) 
2019-05-17 13:06:08.148 11514-11514/com.ahgp E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ahgp/com.ahgp.quickblox_videocalling.activities.CallActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc.QBRTCAudioTrack com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc.QBMediaStreamManager.getLocalAudioTrack()' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2957)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc.QBRTCAudioTrack com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc.QBMediaStreamManager.getLocalAudioTrack()' on a null object reference
at com.ahgp.quickblox_videocalling.activities.CallActivity.initAudioManager(CallActivity.java:396)
at com.ahgp.quickblox_videocalling.activities.CallActivity.onCreate(CallActivity.java:192)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7183)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1220)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2910)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
private AppRTCAudioManager audioManager;

audioManager = AppRTCAudioManager.create(this, new AppRTCAudioManager.OnAudioManagerStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAudioChangedState(AppRTCAudioManager.AudioDevice audioDevice) {

        }
    });
```

And than

```
audioManager.setDefaultAudioDevice(AppRTCAudioManager.AudioDevice.SPEAKER_PHONE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code:

```
private AppRTCAudioManager appRTCAudioManager;

appRTCAudioManager = AppRTCAudioManager.create(this);


if (currentSessionExist() && currentSession.getConferenceType() == QBRTCTypes.QBConferenceType.QB_CONFERENCE_TYPE_AUDIO) {
 appRTCAudioManager.selectAudioDevice(AppRTCAudioManager.AudioDevice.SPEAKER_PHONE);

}
```

And in onSwitchAudio method try this:

```
 @Override
    public void onSwitchAudio() {      
       callService.switchAudio();
    }


public void switchAudio() {
        try {
            Log.v(TAG, "onSwitchAudio(), SelectedAudioDevice() = " + appRTCAudioManager.getSelectedAudioDevice());
            if (appRTCAudioManager.getSelectedAudioDevice() != AppRTCAudioManager.AudioDevice.SPEAKER_PHONE) {
                appRTCAudioManager.selectAudioDevice(AppRTCAudioManager.AudioDevice.SPEAKER_PHONE);
            } else {
                if (appRTCAudioManager.getAudioDevices().contains(AppRTCAudioManager.AudioDevice.BLUETOOTH)) {
                    appRTCAudioManager.selectAudioDevice(AppRTCAudioManager.AudioDevice.BLUETOOTH);
                } else if (appRTCAudioManager.getAudioDevices().contains(AppRTCAudioManager.AudioDevice.WIRED_HEADSET)) {
                    appRTCAudioManager.selectAudioDevice(AppRTCAudioManager.AudioDevice.WIRED_HEADSET);
                } else {
                    appRTCAudioManager.selectAudioDevice(AppRTCAudioManager.AudioDevice.EARPIECE);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
    }
```

**Note**: Update SDK to the latest one and for further details you can check the official link

https://docs.quickblox.com/docs/android-video-calling-advanced